# JavaFx, adding a keypressed event to ComboBoxTableCell

Tags: javafx, combobox, tableview, javafx-8

Can i add a key pressed event to ComboBoxTableCell? if yes please show me how.
Thank you.

Comment: `myComboBoxTableCell.setOnKeyPressed(eventHandler);`

Comment: Thank you fabian for your answer. 
I still don't get it how can it be done. 
there is what i'm doing

Comment: Do the above to the `Cell` before returning it from your `cellFactory`.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick answer, 
Is that what you suggest?
ComboBoxTableCell myComboBoxTableCell=new ComboBoxTableCell();
myComboBoxTableCell.setOnKeyPressed(eventHandler);
column.setCellFactory(myComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(data));

Comment: No: `column.setCellFactory(t -> {ComboBoxTableCell myComboBoxTableCell=new ComboBoxTableCell(); myComboBoxTableCell.setOnKeyPressed(eventHandler); return myComboBoxTableCell;});`